# Open Source .Net Reporting Tool

Tags: .net, visual-studio, reporting-services, reporting

I am looking for a reporting service/tool for visual Studio.  My only restraint is my web server is off limits to me as far as installing ANYTHING.  So I need something I can just include in my project.

My users need to be able to export a report to PDF and without being able to use Crystal I am pretty much lost.

Any ideas?

Answer (score 22, accepted):

[fyireporting](http://www.fyireporting.com/) (released under Apache License) is worth a try.

The fyiReporting RDL Project is a powerful report and charting system based on 
Report Definition Language (RDL).  Tabular, free form, matrix, charts are fully 
supported.  Report output may be displayed as HTML, PDF, XML, .Net Control, 
Web Archive, and to a printer. 
Libraries exist for use in your ASP.NET, Windows .Net, and command line 
applications.

Comment: A popular fork of fyireporting is reportingcloud, now on SouceForge.

Answer (score 5):

Try Microsoft's [ReportViewer](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms251671(VS.80).aspx) system. It to uses the Report Definition Language, but it's ready to go out of the box. It's not Open Source, but it is redistributable.

Comment: would this require a server install though?

Comment: You can include the ReportViewer dlls in your project without needing to install the redistributable package on the server.  The three you need are: Microsoft.ReportViewer.WebForms, Microsoft.ReportViewer.Common,Microsoft.ReportViewer.ProcessingObjectModel.dll.

Comment: Reference them directly in your project with Copy Local.  You may need to get the last one from the GAC first though.

Comment: It's not working under VS 2017 :(

Answer (score 3):

As suggested by Ant, there is also [ReportingCloud](http://sourceforge.net/projects/reportingcloud/) which is a branch of fyiReporting

Answer (score 0):

If you're willing to have no report designer and open source is an absolute requirement, then take a look at [iTextSharp](http://itextsharp.com/) - version 4.0 is totally open source (5.0 you have to pay for comercial use).

There are some additional open source systems listed at [Reporting Software Info](http://www.reportingsoftware.info/).