# Free cross browser reporting tool for ASP.Net

Tags: asp.net, reporting

Is there any free/open source X-browser tool ?

X-browser is primary thing.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

[fyiReporting](http://www.fyireporting.com/)
The fyiReporting RDL Project is a powerful report and charting system based on Report Definition Language (RDL). Tabular, free form, matrix, charts are fully supported. Report output may be displayed as HTML, PDF, XML, .Net Control, Web Archive, and to a printer. Libraries exist for use in your ASP.NET, Windows .Net, and command line applications.

You could refer to [Open Source .Net Reporting Tool](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/202817/open-source-net-reporting-tool)

Comment: I did refer to it before I posted this. However, I am interested in cross browser reporting tools primarily. There is no mention for fyiReporting about it. Also, I see that people give recommendations to Microsoft stuff which is known to be IE-only.

Answer (score 2):

Not sure what you want to do, but if you create PDF reports, you can just use Acrobat Reader, or the Acrobat Browser Plugins to view reports?