# Free alternatives to ReportViewer

Tags: report, reportviewer

In my applications I need to produce two different types of reports.
- one business object per page reports where actual data is written inside appropriate placeholders
- tabular reports spanning multiple pages using grouping and summary rows.

At the moment I' m using ReportViewer, but I'm looking for free alternatives.

I found some similar questions like this [Alternative to reportViewer](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/2638933/alternative-to-reportviewer) , but they are a bit outdated, so in the mind-time new libraries / products may be available.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

In case you are finding some open source and free reporting tools then you should see [fyiReporting](http://www.fyireporting.com/).For further details please see this [question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/2258502/free-cross-browser-reporting-tool-for-asp-net) and [this one as well](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/202817/open-source-net-reporting-tool) where you can also find some open source reporting tools for .net.[iTextSharp](http://itextsharp.com/cgi-sys/defaultwebpage.cgi) also worth to try