# Alternatives for Crystal Report

Tags: c#, crystal-reports

we are switchting from access reports to another solution we startet with crystal reports and had a few problems but we found solutions (e.g. dynamic images) BUT crystal reports doesnt support a subreport in a supreport, so we need a new reporting tool. any sugestions? thanks!

Comment: Oh never tried this, really an interesting requirement. Cna't you think of any other work-around with Crystal Reports? You can see one such work around here: http://www.crystalreportsbook.com/forum/forum_posts.asp?TID=193

Answer (score 2):

[Telerik](http://www.telerik.com/products/reporting.aspx) and [devexpress](http://www.devexpress.com/Products/NET/Reporting/) are two good candidates

Or

look at this [Open Source .Net Reporting Tool](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/202817/open-source-net-reporting-tool)

Answer (score 2):

I'm not sure how much freedom you have amending the reports but in my experience most of the time the vast complexity of reporting comes down to a design flaw.

Spending some time rethinking and rebuilding some reports might give you better performace and you can still use Crystal which is undeniably one of the best reporting tools out there...

Answer (score 1):

I think you will be capable of adding sub-reports within subreports in Perpetuum.  http://www.perpetuumsoft.com .
For the record, I am not working for Perpetuum! Rather I am using it in one of my solutions and think it is pretty useful. But if you have a lot of integration with word, excel etc. I suggest sticking with crystal reports since it is capable of handling OLE better.

Cheers,
Bharath.

Answer (score 0):

1. [SQL Server Reporting Services](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms159106.aspx)
   provides a full range of ready-to-use tools and services to help you create, deploy, and manage     reports for your organization, as well as programming features that enable you to extend and customize your reporting functionality.
2. [DevExpress Reporting Solutions](http://www.devexpress.com/Products/NET/Reporting/)

Answer (score 0):

have you checked [**Telerik Reporting**](http://www.telerik.com/products/reporting.aspx)

Answer (score 0):

I haven't tried the devExpress reporting, but we've had great success with [Telerik Reporting](http://www.telerik.com/products/reporting.aspx).  It has great integration right into VS2008 and its reports are actually built as C# code, and attributes of the report can be configured at run time by setting properties on 'controls' on the report.

Give it a shot, if that isn't what you're after, we've found SQL Server Reporting services sufficient for most of our reporting needs as well.